# Convert numpy.ndarray into pandas DataFrame within an apply function in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, valueerror

I am running the following code in python. However whatever I try I receive the error massage 
"ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

- PyCharm prints an output similar to what I want to achieve (see output). However it does not create a callable item, because of the index error. 
  I am passing an DataFrame(788,6) as input

Can anybody explain how I would be able to great a Dataframe from the results of the acorr_ljungbox test in combination with the apply function? (It returns a tuple with 4 numpy.ndarray elements)

Input:

```
from statsmodels.stats.diagnostic import acorr_ljungbox
import pandas as pd
p = print
data={'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[1,2,3,4,5],'C':[5,4,3,2,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
def box_Lj(series):
    results=acorr_ljungbox(series, range(1,4), boxpierce=True, return_df=True)

    p(results)
    return results
l=df.apply(box_Lj)
```

Output:

```
 lb_stat  lb_pvalue  bp_stat  bp_pvalue
1  1.400000   0.236724     0.80   0.371093
2  1.516667   0.468447     0.85   0.653770
3  4.316667   0.229238     1.65   0.648107
    lb_stat  lb_pvalue  bp_stat  bp_pvalue
1  1.400000   0.236724     0.80   0.371093
2  1.516667   0.468447     0.85   0.653770
3  4.316667   0.229238     1.65   0.648107
    lb_stat  lb_pvalue  bp_stat  bp_pvalue
...
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this a minimum reproducable example, i.e. some code which I can copy and paste and try to look for an error? It is much harder to help if I cannot run the code myself.

Comment: I have changed the code. I solved the problem by just using a loop instead of the apply function. However it would still be interesting to know what the problem is. Using debug, it seems the problem is with the apply function but I am not entirely clear why its not working